# date throws an exception

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a textbox contain a text as

```
18/1/2013
```

i want to take this text as Type datetime. I have tried using the particular code

```
Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.ParseExact(TxtStartDate.Text.Trim(), "dd/MM/yyyy", null));
```

but it throws an exception as

```
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

Comment: That is not an exact parse for `MM`

Comment: Not directly related, You can simply capture the return value from ParseExact. You do not need a Convert again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(TxtStartDate.Text.Trim(), "d/M/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Throws a `FormatException` here in germany. Use `DateTime.ParseExact("18/1/2013", "dd/M/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` instead(`null` will use `CurrentCulture)`.

Comment: `MM` expects Jan as `18/01/2013`. Exactly two chars for month

Comment: @Abhishekgupta Single M reads months till 9th Month without a 0. IF its MM then it requires 09, a zero prefix, in your case 01 for Month.

Comment: @TimSchmelter edited my answer. `ParseExact` should not have had a problem. Will test using german culture.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, verified. That enforces the need to use `InvariantCulture` when you want that to be used. Thanks!

Comment: If this were 8th of January, would it be `"08/1/2013"` or `"8/1/2013"`? Consider using **`"d/M/yyyy"`**. Regarding the German culture: It uses period `"."` as its date separator. Therefore it should be `"18.1.2013"` for that to work. In the invariant culture, the date separator is `"/"`. Inside a format string, the character `/`, unescaped and unquoted, denotes the date separator string of the date format provider used.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Yes, I made the change. Thanks for explaining the interpretation of ` / `.